# Compute the sum of the series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $p_1,...,p_n \in [0,1]$ such that $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n} p_i$ diverges.

**When n goes to $\infty$** the series 
$$p_1 + p_2(1-p_1) +p_3(1-p_1)(1-p_2) + ... + p_n(1-p_1)\cdots(1-p_{n-1})$$ converges? If yes, compute the sum.

Any hints on proving it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $s_n$ be the $n$-th partial sum of the series. Then
$$
 1 - s_n = (1-p_1)(1-p_2) \cdots (1-p_n) \, .
$$
If $p_i = 1$ for any $i$ then $1 - s_n = 0$ for $n \ge i$.

Otherwise
$$
 \log (1-s_n) = \sum_{i=1}^n \log(1-p_i) \le - \sum_{i=1}^n p_i
 $$
Now use that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} p_i$ diverges to infinity.

Comment: I was also writing an answer based on the same observation, but you are faster! (+1) For OP, if it is not clear how the first equality follows, consider $q_n = (1-p_1)\cdots(1-p_n)$ with $q_0 = 1$ and notice that $$ q_{n-1} - q_n = (1-p_1)\cdots(1-p_{n-1})p_n $$ so that your sum telescopes.